# Pandas изменение данных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, в чём дело.
Создаю DataFrame, хочу изменить значение, но ничего не выходит. В чём тут хитрость?

```
data = {'n':[1,1,1,1,1,1], 'bucket':['0','1-30','31-60','91-120','121-150','151-180'], 
'balance':[1899.1644,1899.158,1741.408,1641.7814,1454.0343,1454.0343],
'date':['2016-01-16','2016-02-16','2016-03-16','2016-05-16','2016-06-16','2016-07-16']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.loc[5]['n']=100
```

Результат:

[image: Результат]

В маленьком примерчике такая же ерунда.

```
data = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['d','b','c']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.loc[0]['a'] = 100
print(df)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

НО!!! Если числа, то всё ок:

```
data = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[5,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.loc[0]['a'] = 100
print(df)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas должен был выдать вам предупреждение (Warning), описывающее проблему:

```
In [7]: df.loc[5]['n']=100
C:\Users\Max\Anaconda4\Scripts\ipython3-script.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  if __name__ == '__main__':

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
     balance   bucket        date  n
0  1899.1644        0  2016-01-16  1
1  1899.1580     1-30  2016-02-16  1
2  1741.4080    31-60  2016-03-16  1
3  1641.7814   91-120  2016-05-16  1
4  1454.0343  121-150  2016-06-16  1
5  1454.0343  151-180  2016-07-16  1
```

Как это сделать правильно:

```
In [9]: df.loc[5, 'n'] = 100

In [10]: df
Out[10]:
     balance   bucket        date    n
0  1899.1644        0  2016-01-16    1
1  1899.1580     1-30  2016-02-16    1
2  1741.4080    31-60  2016-03-16    1
3  1641.7814   91-120  2016-05-16    1
4  1454.0343  121-150  2016-06-16    1
5  1454.0343  151-180  2016-07-16  100
```